# SQL joins with where clause

Tags: sql, join

There are two tables - one consist of employee details, and the other contains the order details.

How can I find the name of employee who did not place any order on particular date?

I am using left outer join and my code is like this

```
SELECT 
    emp.FirstName+' '+emp.LastName AS 'FullName', emp.employeeid 
FROM Employee emp
    INNER JOIN Orders oON emp.EmployeeID=o.EmployeeID
WHERE 
    o.OrderDate NOT IN  (SELECT o.OrderDate FROm Orders o WHERE o.OrderDate='4/4/1997')
GROUP BY 
    emp.FirstName+' '+emp.LastName, emp.employeeid
```

but the problem is that its take all the persons in the list.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT emp.FirstName+' '+emp.LastName AS 'FullName', emp.employeeid 
FROM Employee emp LEFT JOIN Orders o 
ON emp.EmployeeID=o.EmployeeID And o.OrderDate='4/4/1997'
where o.EmployeeID is null 
GROUP BY emp.FirstName+' '+emp.LastName, emp.employeeid
```

try this one. should work. and comment answer, as I could't test it on my local...

Comment: u r great man thanks a lot .....u have solved a great problem ......god bless u dear ......lots of thanks

Comment: If this answer helped you solve you problem, you should [**accept this answer**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/153998). This will show your appreciation for the people who *spent their own time to help you*

Answer (score 1):

One method is to use not exists

```
SELECT  
    emp.FirstName+' '+emp.LastName AS 'FullName', emp.employeeid  
FROM Employee emp 
where not exists
    (select * from Orders o ON where emp.EmployeeID=o.EmployeeID 
        and  o.OrderDate='4/4/1997' 
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT FirstName + ' ' + LastName AS 'FullName', 
       employeeid 
FROM Employee
where EmployeeID not in (select EmployeeID 
                         from Orders 
                         where OrderDate = '1997-04-04')
```

Comment: thnks fr help:
SELECT emp.FirstName+' '+emp.LastName AS 'FullName', emp.employeeid 
FROM Employee emp LEFT JOIN Orders o 
ON emp.EmployeeID=o.EmployeeID And o.OrderDate='4/4/1997'
where o.EmployeeID is null 
GROUP BY emp.FirstName+' '+emp.LastName, emp.employeeid

this is the solution